# Why is loading a model in asp.net mvc slow?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, performance, razor

I have a table on a website where the data is coming from a database on a server. I have tried two different approaches and the results were not as I expected.

Note: the data being loaded is about 4000 items

My first approach was to load the data using a model due to the fact that I am using asp.net MVC. Here is my implementation:

```
@foreach (var km in Model)
{
    <tr class="key-row" onclick="KeyTableElementInline_OnClick(this); GetKeyXML(this);">
        <td>@km.key</td>
        <td>@km.hook</td>
        <td>@km.issue_date</td>
        <td>@km.purpose</td>
        <td>@km.holder</td>
        <td>@km.ssn</td>
        <td>@km.advisor</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Although simple, this has a total page load of about 16 seconds

My second approach was to load the data using JS and transfer it via http request. Here is my implementation:

```
const GetMainData = () => {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let xmlDoc = this.responseXML;

            let table = document.getElementsByClassName('key-table-body')[0];
            table.innerHTML = "";

            let roots = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Key");
            document.getElementsByClassName('directory-results')[0].innerHTML = roots.length + " results";

            for (let i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
                let row = document.createElement('tr');
                CreateTableElement(row, roots[i].getElementsByTagName("KeyName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                CreateTableElement(row, roots[i].getElementsByTagName("Hook")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                CreateTableElement(row, roots[i].getElementsByTagName("IssueDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                CreateTableElement(row, roots[i].getElementsByTagName("Purpose")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                CreateTableElement(row, roots[i].getElementsByTagName("Holder")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                CreateTableElement(row, roots[i].getElementsByTagName("SSN")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                CreateTableElement(row, roots[i].getElementsByTagName("Advisor")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

                row.addEventListener("click", KeyTableElementInline_OnClick);
                row.addEventListener("click", GetKeyXML);
                table.insertBefore(row, table.children[0]);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + "/Key/GetMainData", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

const CreateTableElement = (row, value) => {
    let cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.innerText = (value != " ") ? value : "";
    cell.classList.add('align-middle');
    row.appendChild(cell);
}

// Create the table rows on page load
window.onload = GetMainData();
```

This has a total page loadtime of around 6 seconds

I understand load times have a lot to do with the machine they were run on, but these were both ran on the same machine and have a load difference of ~10 seconds. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

If you need any more information about the code just ask :)

Comment: 4000 records is nothing. Where is the bottleneck: client, server or database?

Comment: @iamdlm I timed the data generation server side with a c# stopwatch and it is taking only 78ms to put all of the data into the model. So I would assume its the client

Comment: Have you consider using jQuery to make an ajax request to pull data and use DataTables to present it?

Comment: @iamdlm I am not very experienced in JQuery, but I am also not against using it. On the contrary, the main reason I asked this question was to figure out why using a model was this slow. It just seems odd to be using MVC, but not being able to use the 'Model' portion of it due to it not performing optimally

Comment: It seems odd that your first try was taking so much time with not so much data. Maybe have a look at [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), probably the best option for you.